# Hibernate запись последовательностей транзакций и коммит

Tags: hibernate, java

по-умолчанию гибернейт записывает последовательность команд(оберток над запросами), а потом по требованию комитит. Одна из причин такого подхода - возможность откатить изменения, если произошла ошибка. А зачем еще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Транзакции нужны не только для того, чтобы была возможность отката, но также и для того, чтобы промежуточный результат не мешал логике работы.

Скажем, со счета клиента А списываются деньги и переходят в счет другого клиента Б, транзакция происходят в 2 этапа: сначала списываем бабки со счета А, потом эти же деньги прибавляем к балансу счета Б. Так вот, в случае когда нет транзакций, запрос на сумму счетов А+Б в момент проведения списания со счета А вызовет логическую ошибку, поскольку в воздухе повиснет сумма операции. Фактически это будет означать потерю целостности. Или в терминах [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) - **consistency**.

Comment: а если перевести на язык запросов, то может случится, что N>2 запроса от разных источников к бд могут нарушить целостность и получить неверные результаты?

Comment: Да, если не будет транзакций, то именно все так и случится.